# CFL condition for variable coefficients

Tags: finite-difference, convergence, hyperbolic-pde, cfl

I understand that the constant in the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition is defined as $\mathrm{CFL} = \frac{u \Delta t}{\Delta x}$, where $u$ is the principal coefficient. I came across this post:
[Estimating the Courant number ...](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/estimating-the-courant-number-for-the-navier-stokes-equations-under-differing-re),
which basically suggests that the CFL number can be used to decide on the time step size to ensure stability and convergence. I have seen mentioned in many papers that the results were obtained with for instance $\mathrm{CFL} = 0.5$, which would suggest that the CFL is a constant.

**But how is the CFL number defined if the coefficient $u$ changes with time?**
I am particularly interested in the solution of hyperbolic inviscid Euler equations, where $u = u$, $u+a$ or $u-a$, where the velocity $u$ varies with time and $a$ is the speed of sound.

Comment: The CFL number in your example is defined using the maximum velocity over your domain grid. If your velocity changes with time, then you will have to calculate a new CFL bound at every time step.

Comment: Also, slight clarification on a point that you might have wrong in your mind: the CFL condition does not ensure stability and convergence. Rather, the CFL condition is a necessary condition for stability/convergence. It's a subtle distinction, but it's quite important.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarifications. So am I right that in the case of hyperbolic equations, the maximum of u , |u|+a, and |u|-a is selected as the velocity used to calculate CFL at each time step?

Comment: You're on the right track... Look at the bound for $\Delta t_\mathrm{Hyperbolic}$ in @gnzlbg's answer to the question linked in your original post.

Comment: ok, Thanks. On a slightly different note, I am looking at a wave propagation case, where the speed of sound is sqrt(k/rho) , where rho changes with time also, and k = bulk modulus. In other words my speed of sound also changes. The changes in rho are minimal though, and I wonder if I should just use the initial density in that case?

Comment: You can try to use that "shortcut" and hope everything goes OK, but do you think it would have any significant (positive) impact on the overall runtime and/or code complexity?

Comment: @ChristianClason if you're confident that is really the question, please edit the title and body to say so, and I will write an answer.  I'm not sure.  Notice that you had to change the order of the words to get a question.

Answer (score 5):

The CFL number (or simply Courant number) is defined locally:

$\nu = u(x,t) \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$.

The velocity may vary in time and space and the grid may be non-uniform (in $x$ and/or $t$).  So the CFL number can be different at each point in time and space.
A necessary condition for convergence of a consistent method is that the CFL condition be satisfied at each point in time and space.  Therefore, to choose the timestep one must enforce a bound on the maximum CFL number (maximum in space).